# How to merge different dfs and unstack the values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dict` that has 17 `df` in it.

Sample `dfs`:

`df1`

```
          key                percent
0   step19_without_lof  14.534883720930232
```

`df2`

```
           key                   percent
0   step19_without_lof  14.970930232558139
```

`df3`

```
             key             percent
0   step1_without_lof   1.5988372093023255
1   step2_without_lof   30.377906976744185
2   step5_without_lof   3.197674418604651
3   step7_without_lof   9.738372093023257
4   step12_without_lof  5.377906976744186
5   step15_without_lof  4.215116279069767
6   step16_without_lof  6.8313953488372094
7   step19_without_lof  13.80813953488372
8   step24_without_lof  9.883720930232558
9   step25_without_lof  11.337209302325581
10  step26_without_lof  9.738372093023257
11  step27_without_lof  9.738372093023257
```

and so on.

I would like to merge these `dfs` in such a way that the `key` column becomes the name for each column and the respective values are filled in. In the `df1` and `df2` since there is only one `key`, the remaining `keys` must be filled with `nans`.

**Desired output:**
[image]

**How my dict of dfs looks like:**
[image]

Comment: what does your dictionary look like ? can you post an example, seems like it would be as as simple as `pd.DataFrame(your_dict).T`

Comment: @Datanovice added the screenshot

Comment: I'm not able to make out the format of your dict, but I'm no expert: i was expecting something like this : `dict_ = {'df' : {'key' : 0, 'percent' : 0.5},
        'df2' : {'key' : 1, 'percent' :0.8}}` also please don't post screengrabs of your data. for it to be reproducable we need to copy it into our IDE's to see what works.

Comment: It is not possible to put the dict of dfs, that's why i mentioned that in the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
# append the key to the index (first level is the old index)
# then unstack the key, so the key is converted to columns
df.set_index('key', append=True).unstack('key')
```